# Manifest merger failed with mutliple errors

Tags: android, androidx

Is there any idea how to resolve this issue?

```
  Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha3] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha3] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

Comment: Don't use AndroidX and the support libraries at the same time. Also, do not use the suggest tip from the error. It will not properly fix the error, only ignore it.

Comment: This issue occurs when you use AndroidX and support libraries at the same time. Now the solution is to either use AndroidX libraries or use support libraries but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Find your issue in mergedmanifest on  the android manifest

If the issue is on  appComponentFactory then you have to migrate to androidx

Reason : dependency update

Answer (score 0):

Migrate your dependency to AndroiX,

Auto:

```
Refactor => Migrate to AndroidX
```

Manual:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because android has released a new version and they are depreciating the 28.0.0. The new version is called androidx 1.0.1(beta).This happens because you must have upgraded your android studio or the gradle version of studio.So go to

1)Click Refactor from menu options in Android studio.

2)Click Migrate to Android X from Refactor.

3)It will ask us to create a backup zip file and proceed with backup process. Click migrate.

4) Now this will show the refactor window with the list of all the files using android support libraries. Just click Do Refactor and relax.

5) Now you can see all the support libraries used in the project have been imported to AndroidX dependencies.